# CoreData with NSNumber

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsnumber

I've create a `sqlite` CoreData Application with multiple records inside:

myFile.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * game;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * result;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * totalWin;
```

myFile.m

```
@dynamic game;
@dynamic image;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic resul;
@dynamic totalWin;
```

And i read all in `UITableView` custom, but i will in the first page get a general report for all game, for example:

If i played 5 games i have 5 cells in my `UITableView` how can get the total amount in a unique `NSNumber` like a:

```
UILabel *myTotal;
myTotal = //here i want to get total game from all my cells
```

And in the 5 cells have a NSNumber game:

> ```
> 1St game = 5
> 2St game = 3
> 3St game = 4
> 4St game = 6
> 5St game = 1
> ```

How show in the firsrt page one label with this amount **19**

This is what i load in to a TableView:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [archive count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *gameName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    gameName.text = [archive[indexPath.row]name];

    int gameInt = [[archive [indexPath.row] game]intValue];
    UILabel *gameValue = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    gameValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",gameInt];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How does looks like your `UITableViewDataSource`? What about using `@sum`?

Comment: @Larme add my tableView in a post

Comment: Try `[archive valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.game"];` (or replace `game`, by `resul`, `totalWin` or whatever you want).

Comment: @Larme not working, but i want to show a total in other page non in the cells

Comment: Would you consider displaying the total number of games as a table footer on the same page, or do you require the total number of games displayed separately to the table view on another page?

Comment: @andrewbuilder no I needed in a separate view is a total score and total balance of your games, but thanks

Comment: @Larme THX your simple code was helpful +1 for me

Comment: @Larme you should post your comment as an answer, might be helpful for someone else

Answer (score 1):

**solved with Larme code thanks**

> Try `[archive valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.game"];` (or replace game, by
>   resul, totalWin or whatever you want).